# How can I find out if a support dll is still needed when upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, support

When upgrading to a new Sitecore version, what is the quickest way to see if support dll's are still needed, apart from removing them and testing if everything still works?

Does Sitecore have a page where I can enter the support number (e.g. 432141) and get a 'fixed in version ...'?

Thnx for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same question when upgrading from Sitecore 7.2 to 8.2.

The best approach is to contact Sitecore Support and provide them the list of patches that you have and ask them if they are still required on the upgraded instance.

Reason is because we may think that it is working fine but at the end it still requires that patch. For example, we had the following patch #457624 on Sitecore 7.2 and it was still required on Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 2):

The release notes page that Sitecore puts up for each version contains a list of bugs fixes in the release including the ticket number.  It isn't very searchable but if you're not doing a big version jump this is a place you can look.

For example here are the release notes for [Sitecore 8.2 Update-2](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update2/Release%20Notes)

Comment: Hi Lyle, yes, I know the release notes contain that information,but in some releases there is an 'and other fixes', so you're never sure.
And if you jump several versions, the work is tedious and error prone at best, especially if you have a lot of support dll's.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option available now at
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_home

One can type in the support patch number and it will tell in which Sitecore version that patch has been fixed for example, if one types in KB0511164 it will redirect you to the page describing that issue:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0511164

and on the right hand side there is a table explaining which versions are affected by that issue and which version it has been fixed. In this example you would get the following:

[image]

Comment: but it is not true for all patches because some patches are specially created for particular sites only but most of them we can find here.