# How to check if a hotfix is needed

Tags: installation

I've got a customer who's said they need a hotfix (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/574334). They're on 8.2 Update 3, but the notes for what download to get only goes through 8.1. So I don't know if the fix was integrated somewhere down the line. Is there any way to check beyond reading the release notes for each and every version from 8.1 initial through 8.2 Update 3?

Comment: Ask Sitecore support...

Comment: I've put a request into them as well, but I didn't know if someone here knew of a reference site I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Not exactly the same but similar question here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-support-dll-is-still-needed-when-upgrading

Comment: What makes the client think they need that specific hotfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read all the release notes, and it might be in there. But if you really want to be sure, the best thing to do is ask Sitecore Support. I would assume they have a system that can check these things better than going through release notes ;)

Of course, while waiting for an answer you could still read the notes but that might turn out as a waste of time...

As answered here before ([How can I find out if a support dll is still needed when upgrading?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-support-dll-is-still-needed-when-upgrading)), after upgrading a solution with a bunch of support dlls this "solution" is also the best approach.

I realise this might not be a good solution, but as long as we don't have the tools to easily search for this information and Support probably/hopefully does, we need to bother them with these questions...

Answer (score 3):

What I have done is to open the fix dll's with Reflector, and noticed that it's fixes code from **ParseGenericSearchEngine** from **Sitecore.Analytics**.

Then I've compared code for **ParseGenericSearchEngine** from **Sitecore.Analytics**, from **Sitecore 7.5** and **Sitecore 8.2 update 3**, and I've discovered that **Sitecore 8.2 update 3** has the same code as in **Sitecore 7.5** for **ParseGenericSearchEngine**.

So, I could say that the fix its needed, but as @Gatogordo mentioned before, Sitecore Support should be the one to give you a definitive clear answer.